# Concatenate and Count the multiple rows in single rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, concatenation

I want to concatenate and count data of the same column, so I can concatenate but I can not count the repeated data.

Here's my table of data:

```
| ID  | bills | class |
|-----|-------|-------|
| 1   | 0.5   | 2     |
| 2   | 1     | 1     |
| 3   | 0.5   | 2     |
| 5   | 1     | 3     |
| 6   | 0     | 2     |
| 7   | 0.5   | 1     |
| 8   | 1     | 2     |
| 9   | 1     | 3     |
| 10  | 0.5   | 1     |
| 11  | 0     | 2     |
| 12  | 1     | 1     |
| 13  | 0     | 3     |
| 14  | 1     | 2     |
| 15  | 0     | 1     |
| 16  | 0     | 1     |
| 17  | 0.5   | 3     |
| 18  | 0     | 3     |
| 13  | 0.5   | 3     |
```

Here's my sql query I'm using to concatenate data:

```sql
SELECT class AS lesson,
       GROUP_CONCAT( bills ORDER BY bills ) AS bills
FROM tb_presence
GROUP BY class;
```

Here's my result below:

```
| class | bills            |
|-------|------------------|
| 1     | 1,0.5,0.5,1,0,0  |
| 2     | 0.5,0,1,0,1      |
| 3     | 1,1,0,0.5,0,0.5  |
```

Now I would like to count the data that are equal, but continue with the same concatenation.

I want to "count" the data with the same values ​​and display concatenated (column observation and only to help understanding)

```
| class | bills | observation                 |
|-------|-------|-----------------------------|
| 1     | 2,2,2 | (2=0+0) (2=0.5+0.5) (2=1+1) |
| 2     | 2,1,2 | (2=0+0) (1=0.5) (2=1+1)     |
| 3     | 2,2,2 | (2=0+0) (2=0.5+0.5) (2=1+1) |
```

Is this really possible?

Comment: can you provide exact output you're expecting to get?

Comment: You should try and use `select distinct`

Comment: Try to tell us what you need, based on the following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb0b56/1).

Comment: Hi Mureinik, see below:

I want to "count" the data with the same values ​​and display concatenated (column observation and only to help understanding)

class   bills          observation 
1          2,2,2         (2=0+0) (2=0.5+0.5) (2=1+1) 
2          2,1,2         (2=0+0) (1=0.5) (2=1+1) 
3          2,2,2         (2=0+0) (2=0.5+0.5) (2=1+1)

Comment: Are there only 3 values for bills? -> 0, 0.5 & 1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (thanks to @wchiquito for the sqlfiddle) See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d2c8/1

As you can see it cannot dynamically determine the bills' values and count them. But there is a count per bill value that you want.

```
SELECT class AS lesson,
GROUP_CONCAT( bills ORDER BY bills ) AS bills
,SUM(IF(bills=0,1,0)) AS Count0
,SUM(IF(bills=0.5,1,0)) AS Count05
,SUM(IF(bills=1,1,0)) AS Count1
,COUNT(*) AS totalRecords
,COUNT(*) 
  - SUM(IF(bills=0,1,0))
  - SUM(IF(bills=0.5,1,0))
  - SUM(IF(bills=1,1,0))
  AS Missing
FROM tb_presence GROUP BY class;
```

I added an extra record to show how the 'missing' column could show if you were not taking all values into consideration.

Results

```
| LESSON |                                   BILLS | COUNT0 | COUNT05 | COUNT1 | TOTALRECORDS | MISSING |
|--------|-----------------------------------------|--------|---------|--------|--------------|---------|
|      1 | 0.00,0.00,0.50,0.50,1.00,1.00,1.00,4.00 |      2 |       2 |      3 |            8 |       1 |
|      2 |           0.00,0.00,0.50,0.50,1.00,1.00 |      2 |       2 |      2 |            6 |       0 |
|      3 |           0.00,0.00,0.50,0.50,1.00,1.00 |      2 |       2 |      2 |            6 |       0 |
```